# Apple Watch screen not turning off anymore

Tags: apple-watch

Usually my Apple Watch's screen turns on when I raise my arm, and then it turns off either when I put my arm down, or if I leave my arm in that position for 15 seconds. This has always been the case

For some reason this isn't happening anymore, since around yesterday. When I raise my arm, the screen remains on even when I put my arm down, and also doesn't seem to turn off even when I wait for it to.

What can I do in this circumstance?

Comment: Have you activated 'Theater Mode'?  If so, you should see 2 orange face masks on the top of the screen.

Comment: That causes the screen *not* to turn on when you lift your arm. The issue I'm facing is quite particular – it almost seem to be doing the opposite.

Comment: I'm just checking everything I can think of.  Take a look at [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8040358) and see if any of these help you.  If any do help, I can add it as an answer for you.

Comment: All right, thanks! I fixed it by restarting anyway. Strange bug...

Comment: I'm glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by restarting both my watch and my paired phone simultaneously (restarting only the watch potentially would have solved the problem). Right now it is turning off as expected.

Comment: Anytime anything iOS doesn't work right the first step is always: restart the device.